# How to rearrange 36-bit character string using Pseudo-Random Number Generator (PRNG)

Tags: python, url, encoding, random, decode

I have made a program to encode and decode long URL's. Encode will take n characters and outputs a 36-bit character string. Decode will take a 36-bit character string and output a long character string.

```
print(decode(encode(1234567890)))
'1234567890'
```

So basically, something that will randomize a 36-bit string and it's decode opposite. Is there a way using a pseudo random number generator to make the properties of a seeded PRNG reversible and use some invariant property of the numbers to seed the PRNG.

I know bits and pieces of this code, these might help.

```
def ls1b( x ):  

"""Return least significant bit of x that is a one. (Assume x >= 0.)"""

return x & -x
```

And

```
def bitson( x ):

"""Return the number of one bits in x. (Assume x >= 0.)"""

count = 0

while x != 0:

    x &= ~ls1b( x )

    count += 1

return count
```

Here is my encode and decode.

```
def token (n):
if n < 10:
    return chr( ord( '0' ) + (n) )
if n in range (10, 36):
    return chr( ord( 'A' ) - 10 + (n))
if n in range (37, 62):
    return chr( ord( 'a' ) - 36 + (n))
if n is 62:
    return '-'
if n is 63:
    return '+'


def encode (n):
a = n // 1 % 64
b = n // 64 % 64
c = n // 64 ** 2 % 64
d = n // 64 ** 3 % 64
e = n // 64 ** 4 % 64
f = n // 64 ** 5 % 64
return (token(a) + token(b) + token(c) + token(d) + token(e) + token(f))



def tokend (d):
x = ord(d)
if 48 <= x <= 57:
    return x - ord('0')
if 65 <= x <= 90:
    return x - ord('A') + 10 
if 97 <= x <= 122:
    return x - ord('a') + 36
if x is 43:
    return ('62')
if x is 45:
    return ('63')


def decode(code, base=64):
    if base>64:
            return 'error: too few symbols'
    code=str(code)
    o=0
    e=0
    for i in code:
            o=o+detoken(i)*base**e
            e=e+1
    while len(str(o))<6:
            o='0'+str(o)
    return o
```

Comment: Are you trying to shorten the URL like tinyurl? Also, why decode outputs a "36-bit" but encode takes "6 characters"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to do a reversible hash function, right? Or maybe something like compressing function?

Comment: I have already been successful shortening URL's. And, sorry, I didn't mean to say it only encodes 6 characters. It can encode any length of characters. What I am trying to do, is to randomize the outputs of both encode and decode operations.

Comment: I just mixed them up. I hope the edits help.

Answer (score 1):

PRNGs are deterministic for any given seed, so yes it is definitely possible to create a function which uses a PRNG with a given seed to encode data, and then decode that data if the original seed and PRNG function are known.  This is, in fact, why certain cryptographic functions have weaknesses (like GSM A5/1 in cell phones).

One possible avenue you could explore to create such a scheme (speaking of A5/1) is using a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).  I am suggesting this under the presumption that you are not trying to create something that is cryptographically secure.  If you are trying to create something secure, you shouldn't invent your own scheme, but instead use an existing well-tested scheme.